# How to use Skype for Business (full client) after upgrading to Firefox 52+?

Tags: firefox, microsoft-outlook, skype-for-business, npapi

I have a client with whom I frequently communicate using Skype for Business meetings. The common use case is that they sends me an invitation to a Skype meeting (hosted on their system), which I open in Outlook. Clicking the link opens Firefox (default browser) with a start page, which loads the plugin. Since my machine has the full Skype for Business client installed, the plugin simply forwards to it.

That was up to Firefox 51. This week I got the update to Firefox 52, which dropped NPAPI support. As a result, the Skype for Business plugin is no longer available.

Is there a way to bypass the plugin (or browser+plugin) and open the meeting directly in the Skype for Business client? Switching browsers is explicitly not an option.

The link I get in Outlook looks roughly like this:

`https://server.example.com/examplegroup.net/meet/john.doe/D452VK6R`

Comment: What does the link in outlook look like? What protocol is it?

Comment: @DavidPostill It’s an HTTPS link to the client’s server, I’ve updated the question.

Comment: Is it an option to just open the link in IE/Edge?

Comment: @Seth not really, because there are some issues with proxy and VPN, and the settings IE gets via policy never worked correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I got one step further.

If I copy the URL from the invitation, paste it into Firefox and add a prefix like this:

`conf:sip:https://server.example.com/examplegroup.net/meet/john.doe/D452VK6R`

Skype for Business opens and tries to connect.

Alas, the connection fails with the message:

`Cannot join the meeting due to user permissions.`

This is apparently due to a [region bug](http://www.ultimate-communications.com/2012/11/the-good-old-region-bug-is-back-in-lync-server-2013-lync/) on the server, which looks like a separate issue.